# Proving the nth derivative of a polynomial of degree n-1 is zero using linear Algebra.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

I want to prove by using linear algebra only that the nth derivative of a polynomial of degree n-1 is zero. My idea is using proving first that every square matrix $A$ such the only not zero entries are those that $j=i+1$ then $A^{n}=0$.

Then by noticing that for the derivative operator $D:P_{n}(\mathbb{R}) \to P_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ and the canonical basis $\beta= \lbrace 1, x,x^{2},...,x^{n} \rbrace$ of the vector space $P_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ we have that $[D]_{\beta}$ is such the entry $j=i+1$ then $([D]_{\beta})^{n}=0$ so the nth derivaritve of a polynomial can be seen in a matrix representation as

$$ [D^{n}p(x)]_{\beta}=[D^{n}]_{\beta}[p(x)]_{\beta}=([D]_{\beta})^{n}[p(x)]_{\beta}=0 [p(x)]_{\beta}=0 $$

Proving that the  the nth derivaritve of a polynomial of degree $n-1$ is zero but this also proves thath the nth derivative of a polynomial of degrees $n$ is zero which is not true. So.. what I am doing wrong and end up the proof of this only using linear algebra? Thanks

Comment: The derivative operator matrix is a superdiagonal matrix, hence it is nilpotent.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $[D]_{\beta}$ is an $(n+1)\times (n+1)$ matrix. What we actually have is that $([D]_{\beta})^{n+1} = 0$, not $([D]_{\beta})^n=0$.

Comment: Got it @OpenBall but this also implies that $ [D^{n}p(x)]_{\beta} \neq 0 $.

Comment: @Cos yes but it implies $D^{n+1} p(x) = 0$. Your $n-1$ is my $n$ and your $n$ is my $n+1$.

Comment: what degree is your $p(x)$ is a polynomial in the last comment ? @OpenBall

Comment: @Cos it's anything $\le n$.

Comment: This still does not prove thath for a polynomial of degree  $\leq n$then  $D^{n} p(x)=0$ . Dont got it, sorry. @OpenBall

Comment: I already got it! Thanks!!